# Mouse click input lag

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, linux

I have just installed Linux Mint 18 with a view to using it as my daily driver, but I am noticing a small amount of mouse click input lag in tf2 - just enough to throw off my rocket jumping and for me to notice when using hitscan weapons. Is there a way to solve (or even quantify) this? I have tried with and without raw input and in both windowed and fullscreen modes.

Mouse: Logitech G402

GPU: GTX 970

Driver: nvidia 361.42-0ubuntu2

Kernel: 4.4.0-34-generic

Answer (score 1):

Check out the second to last post on [this thread here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/648817378145004667/). It suggests taking the following steps (pasted from that thread):

> First you need to disable mouse acceleration in xinput:
>
> Open terminal, type:
>
> `xinput list`
>
> You should get an output that looks something like this:
>
> `Yourname@machinename ~ $ xinput list ⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] ⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜ ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse id=9 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜ ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)] ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)] (There'll be a bit more data here but it's pointer section we're interested in)`
>
> The following steps I did for 3 different ids (2,9 and 11, pretty sure
> I actually only needed to do it for 11 now but I was in a rush and
> couldn't be bothered figuring out which one at the time lol).
>
> Using id 9 as an example, you then want to add:
>
> `xinput list-props 9`
>
> The default output should look something like:
>
> `Device 'Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse': Device Enabled (141): 1 Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 Device Accel Profile (269): 0 Device Accel Constant Deceleration (270): 1.000000 Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (271): 1.000000 Device Accel Velocity Scaling (272): 10.000000 Device Product ID (259): 6940, 6917 Device Node (260): "/dev/input/event18" Evdev Axis Inversion (273): 0, 0 Evdev Axes Swap (275): 0 Axis Labels (276): "Rel X" (151), "Rel Y" (152), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (291) Button Labels (277): "Button 0" (290), "Button Unknown" (262), "Button Unknown" (262), "Button Wheel Up" (147), "Button Wheel Down" (148), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (149), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (150) Evdev Middle Button Emulation (278): 0 Evdev Middle Button Timeout (279): 50 Evdev Third Button Emulation (280): 0 Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (281): 1000 Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (282): 3 Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (283): 20 Evdev Wheel Emulation (284): 0 Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (285): 0, 0, 4, 5 Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (286): 10 Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (287): 200 Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (288): 4 Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (289): 0`
>
> You want to change the Device Accel Profile (269) and Device Accel
> Constant (270)... To do this use:
>
> `sudo xinput set-prop 9 269 -1`
>
> `sudo xinput set-prop 9 270 2`
>
> Replace 9 with your device id, replace 269/270 with the parameter id
> if different, -1/2 is the attribute). These changes are not permanent
> and will need to be reapplied after reboot. You can set them as a
> script to run at boot if you want it to be permanent.
>
> Second you need to disable the touchpad option in mouse settings
> (menu>prefs>mouse... untick it).
>
> And finally you need to set mouse polling rate to 1000Hz (if your
> mouse supports it that high as most modern gaming mice do, try
> 500/250/125 etc if not):
>
> `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
>
> Add the lines:
>
> `-r usbhid usbhid mousepoll=1`
>
> Different poll rate values you could use here:
>
> 1000hz = 1
>
> 500hz = 2
>
> 250hz =4
>
> 125hz=8
>
> 100hz = 10
>
> So for a gaming mouse use 1, for an old mouse you might have to use
> 10.
>
> Save and close.